# How to create a .exe file for running command prompt commands

Tags: testing, cmd, automation, automated-tests, exe

I wish to put the following steps in a .exe file so that manual intervention is avoided and everything is automated. All the user needs to do is double click this .exe file.

Following are the steps which I wish to automate.

1. Open command prompt.
2. Go to desired folder location Eg. cd Desktop\Automation\
3. Run the command ruby xyz.rb

Thanks!
Abhishek

Comment: Assuming this is on Windows, just put those commands in a batch file (.bat).